# How to upload the default checkout procedure in magento

Tags: magento, checkout

i am trying to fix a magento shop that another developer built.
The shop is multilanguage and i see the checkout progress block at step 3.
you can watch it here: http://www.ac-sw.net/

I need to return back to the original checkout process, i tryed to upload the app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/checkout.xml, and the app/design/frontend/default/default/template/checkout folder without any change.

How can i return back to the default and working checkout procedure?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Magento admin, you may want to check:

System > Configuration > Design > Themes

In this section clear all the options and make sure **Default** is set to

```
default
```

This will tell Magento to use the 'default' theme instead of a custom theme.

Comment: already done, they edit the default theme a lot, and i am trying restore only the checkout part.